# How to change TDengine database default parameter

Tags: tdengine

After searching TDengine online documentation: https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/, I found the the command to change the default database parameter "keep", which indicates how long data will be preserved in databases. However after I have typed in that command from shell, "show variables" command still shows the old value. How would I know if changing this parameter is taking effect?

```
taos> alter database test keep 50;
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.019087s)
taos> show variables;
           name           |             value              |
============================================================
 version                  | 2.1.5.0                        |
 buildinfo                | Built at 2021-08-05 23:49:17   |
 walLevel                 | 1                              |
 comp                     | 2                              |
 precision                | 0                              |
 maxRows                  | 4096                           |
 minRows                  | 100                            |
 keep                     | 3650                           |
```

Answer (score 0):

the `alter` command  is effective at the DataBase level, and `show varibles` is show the global parameters.
you can use `show databases;` to check the database's parameter.

if you want change the `show variables;`'s show, you should modify the config file `/etc/taos.cfg`

and there are only serval parameters can modify by `alter` command.